# need help bulding a peace of code need to add a object to an array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I have this table view which has to add button.
this add button opens a view where the user can enter something in a textfield.
when the user is done he pressed a done button which put the text in the textfield in to 2 public variables then it spawn the tableview again but when the table view is spawned again it has the entered text as a object i need this process so it can be done unlimited times. but i don't know who i can make this please help

i have been traying to make this code by my self and this is what i got to

this is the tableview

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    if(appdel.sExerciseName != NULL){

        NSString *newitem = appdel.sExerciseName;

            appdel.newExerciseArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:newitem, nil];

NSLog(@" number of objects in array is %i",[appdel.newExerciseArray count]);

        int x = 0;
        do{




NSLog(@"23  pos is : %i and object is %@",x,[appdel.newExerciseArray objectAtIndex:x]);

            for (int y =0; y<[appdel.newExerciseArray count]; y++) {
                [exercises addObject:[appdel.newExerciseArray objectAtIndex:x]];

            }
            x++;
        }while (x<[appdel.newExerciseArray count]);
        appdel.sExerciseName = NULL;
        [Table reloadData];  
    } }
```

this is the donebutton

```
-(IBAction)DonPressed{

  appdel.sExerciseName = NameField.text;
appdel.sExerciseTimes = timesField.text;


NSLog(@"name %@ and times is %@ button pressed1",appdel.sExerciseName , appdel.sExerciseTimes);

exercisesViewControler *detailViewController = [[exercisesViewControler alloc] initWithNibName:@"exercisesViewcontroler" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
[detailViewController release];
}
```

so this code works first time but when i due it second time it just overwrite the old object / item in the array with contains the data off the table view

sry for my english and please keep in mind when you answer keep it simple so i can understand as a noob developer

Comment: Could you please reformat your code (coherent indentation, etc.)? That way, people can help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is, that you are creating new instances of exercisesViewController when you are done, by calling:

```
[[exercisesViewControler alloc] initWithNibName:@"exercisesViewcontroler" bundle:nil];
```

But what yout want to do is to keep the object. Instead you could do the following:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

So your new method will look like:

```
-(IBAction)DonPressed{
    appdel.sExerciseName = NameField.text;
    appdel.sExerciseTimes = timesField.text;
    NSLog(@"name %@ and times is %@ button pressed1",appdel.sExerciseName , appdel.sExerciseTimes);

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: dosent make any difference still keeps over writing the item/object THAT i just addet

the code you gave me have only make what window it starts different

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I thought your exerciseViewController was your RootViewController. So replace your first code: `exercisesViewControler *detailViewController = [[exercisesViewControler alloc] initWithNibName:@"exercisesViewcontroler" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
[detailViewController release];` with `popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated`

Comment: so i have to repleace is line of code [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
with 
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:detailViewController animated:YES];
???

Comment: wow ty you don't wanna know who menu hours i spend trying to solv this problem !!!!